# Compile/Execute XAML during program runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, runtime, code-generation

I would like to create an WPF Application which retrieves XAML Code from a Database and displays the retrieved code.

Lets say the database return the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Button Content="test case 1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="100" 
                Click="TestCase1_OnClick" 
                Height="29"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do i execute this code (or maybe just the content of the mainGrid) during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved the problem:

I have 3 files MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.xaml.cs and wpftest.csproj.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="wpftest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace wpftest
{
    using System.Windows;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world", "does it work?");
        }
    }
}
```

**wpftest.csproj** 
(Note: this file is very large and the most of the stuff is not necessary. You could create a much more simplified solution by following this guide: [Walkthrough: Creating an MSBuild Project File from Scratch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd576348.aspx) )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{E3FBAE41-AF7E-4C7E-A69E-ADAEAEE76FA2}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>wpftest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>wpftest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Solution:**

The following code snippet will compile the code, created the dll file and use the created dll via reflection. This happens (all) during the application runtime.

Special thanks to [doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115749/doug) for this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921184/running-msbuild-through-code-and-getting-asynchronous-progress)

```
    private void TestCase4_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(@"C:\Users\jbu\wpftest\wpftest.csproj", globalProperties, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
        var pc = new ProjectCollection();

        var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), buildRequest);

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\jbu\wpftest\bin\Debug\wpftest.dll");
        var instance = assembly.CreateInstance("wpftest.MainWindow") as Window;

        if (instance != null)
        {
            instance.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

[XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class is intened for this purpose. Use its [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee149743.aspx) method to load the xaml dynamically.

EDIT - This link [here](http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/21/wpf-dynamically-compile-and-run-event-handlers-within-loose-xaml-using-codedom/) might be of your interest.

Comment: As far as i know XamlReader won't work for event handler (Click="TestCase1_OnClick")

Comment: Yeah, you can't create handlers with it since it's not `loose XAML` anymore. Only loose XAML can be loaded with it.

Comment: Why do you want to load XAML from the Database. If you explain what you are trying to achieve maybe an alternate implementation can be suggested. For example I would rather have templates built internally , and then get parameters from DB than storing Xaml in the DB.

Comment: @Joel - I think you should redesign your code. But however if you want to stick to it, you can use `CodeDom` to create handlers dynamically. Link here http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/21/wpf-dynamically-compile-and-run-event-handlers-within-loose-xaml-using-codedom/ might be of your interest.

Comment: There is no Database, i just created a case to point out the problem. The real problem is much more complicated. But well, lets give it a shot here is what i try to achieve: I receive an user interface defined in an XML File and a corresponding c# code behind file from a webservice. The XML file must be parsed to XAML. Then i have to display the generated XAML file somehow. Basically i have to create a user interface out of an xml file at runtime.

Comment: this might be helpful, i will post some demo code later. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I want to suggest a better way without compiling in runtime.

1. Replacing the "click" attribute with "Command". Implement your Relay command or other third party libraries ( Eg: [MVVM Light toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) 
   ) . Also [ICommand MVVM implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/icommand-mvvm-implementation/1468830#1468830) would help.
2. Remove `x:Class` attribute from xaml of Window node.

Now you have a loose xaml and task could be done by XamlReader.