# WPF get xaml of controls created at runtime

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml

Like Visual studio or any other IDE, Dynamically created controls in a tab page has to be saved and retrieved back is the task. I have tried the methodology of converting mycontrolsclass which has dynamically created controls in a list into json which will be saved to database and retrieved back. The stackoverflow error happens when the entire mycontrolsclass has been serialised to json. So thought of having a xaml content to database. Several tutorials helps out to get xaml content of a wpf window physical file but not aware of getting a xamlcontent out of a window which has dynamically created controls.

Tried looping through LogicalTreeHelper class too but i couldnt get the exact xaml. Is my methodology correct or how can i get xaml for dynamically created controls?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15003183/1997232) is something similar. You can also search separately for "xaml load runtime" and "xaml save runtime" (should lead you to related questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [`XamlWriter.Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.save(v=vs.110).aspx) is that what you're looking for.

Comment: Great help, but xaml serialize error happens as follows which i couldnt overcome. 
an unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot serialize a non-public type 'FormsSuite.CustomControl.CustomTabItem'.

Comment: @ArulManivannan Just make `FormsSuite.CustomControl.CustomTabItem` public, that should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm, was hesitant to put that error in the previous comment. Now your comment too has helped me to save some days. Thanks.